# Permutations of all the digits that can be used as a number again

Tags: c++, combinatorics

In C++ what is the best way of generating of all permutations of digits of some number if I need to use these permutations as number further on in my code?

Suppose I have this `int n = 12345`. I need to generate all the permutations, e. g. 12354, 12435, etc. and be able to use them as numbers.

Certainly, I can extract each digit, put all the digits into a vector and run *std::next_permutation*, but that seems brute-force to me. Is there anything more elegant?

Comment: The problem with an open ended "what is the best way to do X" in C++, is that if you pose this question to three C++ developers you will get four different answers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: dont do premature optimization. If you have an idea for a brute force way, then implement it, while doing so you might already get ideas on how to improve it. Anything is more elegant than nothing

Comment: What exactly is inelegant with using `next_permutation`? Sounds like a bad case of not invented here syndrome.

Comment: You haven't specified what to do about duplicate digits or leading zeros.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm ok with than, I will choose what I think is the best option.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I'm going to do that in a loop for a large number of numbers, so I thought there might be something better that constantly converting numbers to vectors and vectors to numbers.

Comment: @stark there will be no leading zeros and in case of duplicate digits there will be fewer permutations, so 113 will give 131 and 311, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" C++ solution is to use C++ elements / algorithms that are specifically designed for the required purpose. And, if you want to have permutations, then `std::next_permutation` is the way to go.

So, we will first convert the value to a string, then get all permutations and convert each permutation to a number. With that number we can work.

Please see:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Some test number
    constexpr unsigned int number{ 54321 };

    // Convert to string and sort the digits
    std::string s{ std::to_string(number) };
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

    // Work with all permutations
    do {
        // Get the associated value
        unsigned long value{ std::stoul(s) };

        // Do what ever you want with the value
        std::cout << value << "\n";

    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

Please note: There are at least 42 other solutions and maybe better ones in respect to code size, speed or whatever requirement you may have. . .